# How to interpret an early sudden increase of the loss function, then a normal decrease?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

How to interpret an early sudden increase of the loss function, then a normal decrease ?

Data : 128x128x4 images (randomly splitted : 60%train, 20% val, 20% test)
gt : one hot encoded 128x128x3 (because 3 different classes)

model : unet (image segmentation)
lr : 0.01 to 0.0001 (lr decrease on plateau)
Batch size : 16

Here are the graphs of my training :
[loss on validation set (inference)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk1C3.png) and
[training loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4cQW.png)

Why during the first 3 inferences, loss is decreasing, then suddenly increase during a single epoch ?

Comment: Your algorithm is trying to learn how to approximate some function. If you think of that function as a mountain range, sometimes you have to wander up a bit before you can figure out which way leads downward. Depending on the situation, this can be perfectly normal.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the "loss" function is simply an error metric for that iteration.  For most models, this rises and falls somewhat through training, with a general downward trend.

What you see simply says that an early guess was rather good, for the entire profile of model weights.  However, that guess was "right for the wrong reasons".  There are many ways this can happen.  One I've seen several times is in the "dog v cat" image model.  Shuffling the data sometimes brings up several early batches in which cat photos are generally indoors, and dog photos are generally outside.  The early training then learns to associate "cat" with furniture, and "dog" with lawn/trees/flowers.  When the rest of the data set shows up, all of those learning nodes need to be thrown out and retrained, causing a large spike in the loss function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, model is nothing but a equation(or set of rules) contains parameter(weights) and forms. For example f(x)=W1X1 + W2X2 + W3X3, here w1,w2 and w3 are known as weights and x1, x2 and x3 are forms.

So initially the model guesses the weights by its own and when the first input comes, it feed into the model(equation) and gives the output, now you can see for the input the model itself guessed the parameter so it might produce output that is very far away from ground ground_truth. And after that it compares the hypothesis with the ground truth, compute the loss, perform optimisation and update the weight, initially due to guess the loss might be very large but gradually it decreases with every update(that's what happening in your case).If the loss gradually fluctuating, that's completely normal.

And if, after some epoch your loss suddenly increased that means there is issue with your learning rate. Change your learning(increase or decrease) rate and analyse your model how it behaves.

Comment: yes, ty for your answer. But the strange think is that it increase after some decreasing epochs... and my learning rate change only if I reach a plateau.